# How do I convert horizontal inward motion to vertical downwards motion

Tags: kinematics, electronics, robotics-library, mechanical-engineering

[image]I have a small coil gun project for which I designed a magazine to put my soft iron projectiles, my main concern is to design some sort of magazine mechanism with a safety because the “accelerator” is quite powerful. I devised a system where if I push a trigger a stopper opens and the magnetic pull of the coil pulls the projectile in and propels it. The problem is how do I convert the pushing of a trigger to the downward pulling of the stopper

*im a high schooler with very basic knowledge of robotics, kinematics and electrical engineering*

*sorry for the bad drawing and weird component names I’m really NEW at this*

Comment: a string might be suitable ... difficult to comment without a diagram

Comment: I can upload my rough diagram